# NameError: name 'savefile' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, function

Here is my code, I'm having issues trying to get this to run. I keep getting a failure when trying to execute:

I am referencing this function the same way I am trying to reference this one? I'm not sure what's going on?

#### PARSING RESULTS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "masscanner.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "masscanner.py", line 43, in main
    file = write_file(savefile)
NameError: name 'savefile' is not defined



def write_file(savefile):
    print('\n\n########## WRITING FILE ##########\n')
    fh = open("endpointslist", "w")
    for i in savefile:
        fh.write(i[0])
        fh.write('\n')

def main():
    """ Main program """
    results = find_endpoints()
    ipportset = parse_results(results)
    fh = write_file(savefile)
    pprint(ipportset)
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Where is `savefile` defined? You pass it to `write_file` in `fh = write_file(savefile)` but never declare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible that its just a typo. Shouldn't it be `write_file(ipportset)`. In the context, the variable `savefile` comes from nowhere and is therefore giving you the error `NameError: name 'savefile' is not defined`